# Perl - Get value in nested array of arrays

Tags: perl

I have a variable (`$issue`) that contains various values that I need to pull a single value (emailAddress) from.  The contents of `$issue` (via `Data::Dump`) is:

```
'fields' => {
    'reporter' => {
        'name' => 'jeremywilson',
            'displayName' => 'Jeremy Wilson',
            'key' => '15429',
            'emailAddress' => 'jwilson@syslog.com',
            'timeZone' => 'America/New_York',
            'active' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )
    },
    'customfield' => [
        {
            'active' => $VAR1->{'fields'}{'reporter'}{'active'},
            'timeZone' => 'America/New_York',
            'emailAddress' => 'mexample@nowhere.com',
            'key' => 'mexample',
            'name' => 'mexample',
            'displayName' => 'Mike Example'
        }
    ],
}
```

I get the first email via `$issue->{fields}->{'reporter'}->{'emailAddress'}` but how do I get the value from `customfield`?

Comment: `$issue->{fields}->{customfield}[0]->{emailAddress}`? A [mcve] would help...

Comment: Yes, that works!  Thanks.

Comment: Or you could use `$issue->{fields}{customfield}[0]{emailAddress}` to make record shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments include two answers

```
$issue->{fields}->{customfield}[0]->{emailAddress}
```

and a shorter, but also correct

```
$issue->{fields}{customfield}[0]{emailAddress}
```

These answer the question that was asked, but likely, more clarification is needed for a general answer, for example, when there are more than one customfield, or if customfield is optional, how will the data be represented?